# Is this function continuous on $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. On what subsets is this function
>   (dis)continuous?
>
> $g(z) = \frac{sin|z|}{z}$

My attempt:

Write $z = x + iy$. Then:

$g(z) = \frac{\sin|z|}{z} = \frac{sin(x^2 + y^2)}{x+iy}$

Obviously, this is undefined when $z = 0$, so it is not continuous at this point.

I am fairly certain that the rest is continuous (i.e. on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$) since the sine function is continuous, but how would I show it?

Comment: Hint: Differentiability implies continuity.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris thanks, but we have not yet covered differentiability in the textbook (next section).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
You can write your map as:

$g(z)=\frac{sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}(x-iy)$

Comment: Thanks. So, is it correct to say that $g$ is continuous everywhere except at $z=0$ because we can re-write the function as $\frac{\sin(w)}{w}(x-iy)$ for some $w > 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and we know that $\frac{\sin(w)}{w}$ is continuous (from real analysis / calculus)?

Comment: No, the function is not defined in z=0 but you can observe that the limit of this function in z=0 is finite and it is zero so  the function is continuos on C\0 but it can be extended to a continuos function on all C

Comment: yes so... it is continuous everywhere it is defined in $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. everywhere except 0).